# Is "recycling" Mishloach Manot halachically acceptable?

Tags: halacha, mishloach-manot

Inevitably, this happens to me almost every year.

I give *mishloa'ch manot* to Shmer'l. Shmer'l take some of my *mishloa'ch manot* and gives it to Chatzkel. Chatzkel, not knowing that the huge chicken-filled hamantash came from me, puts it in the mishloa'ch manot sent to me. Simce Chatzkel appeared at my door, can I take "his" hamantash (which was originally mine), put in a box with one other item, and give it back to him, or must I include new stuff that didn't get recycled?

I listed the more complex case, first. Here's the simpler "recycling case":

Yartug appears at my door, and gives me his mishlo'ach manot package. I take it in my hand (so, technically, I guess, it's mine by making a *kinyan*. Can I now give it back to Yartug?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bixzobAHCGU

Comment: @DoubleAA - The Hebrew was a bit too fast for me, but I got the idea. Very clever :-) Thanks much.

Comment: http://www.aish.com/h/pur/t/har/48959536.html

Comment: Why not ask Shemrel what he thinks of this? https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/16708/shmerel  ;)

Comment: In The Rav Thinking Aloud  p. 14-15 the following is recorded: "R. Chaim once made an enemy this way. A rich *gevir* gave R. Chaim an expensive platter of exotic fruits for *mishloach manos*. As the *gevir* was leaving, an *ani* came to the door, and R. Chaim gave him the entire basket."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

(Skip to the last paragraph for the short summary.)

There is an explicit source that this is allowed.

[Rambam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maimonides) rules ([Hilchos Megilla 2:15](http://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?sefer=3&hilchos=21&perek=2&halocha=15&hilite=)) that if one cannot afford to give mishloach manos, he can send his meal to his friend and have the friend send his meal to him.

> ואם אין לו מחליף עם חברו זה שולח לזה סעודתו וזה שולח לזה סעודתו כדי
>   לקיים ומשלוח מנות איש לרעהו

This is based on the Gemara ([Megilla 7b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=11&daf=7b&format=pdf)) which states that Abbaye and R. Chanina would send each other their meals.

> אביי בר אבין ור' חנינא בר אבין מחלפי סעודתייהו להדדי

However, [Rashi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rashi) interprets the Gemara differently. He says that it means that one year one would go to the other for the meal, and the next year they would reverse it.

> זה אוכל עם זה בפורים של שנה זו ובשניה סועד חברו עמו

The [Beis Yosef](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_Karo) ([O.C. 695](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x2821)) asks how they fulfilled their obligation of mishloach manos according to Rashi if only one of them was giving each year, and he does not have a good answer.

> ורש"י פירש מחלפי סעודתייהו זה אוכל עם זה בפורים של שנה זו ובשנייה סועד
>   חבירו עמו וקשה לי על דבריו דאם כן לא היו מקיימים משלוח מנות איש לרעהו
>   וא"ת שהיו שולחים מנות איש לרעהו אם כן מאי אתא לאשמועינן

The [Lechem Mishneh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham_de_Boton), however, answers ([Hilchos Megilla 2:15](http://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?mfid=91341&rid=2820)) that what Rashi meant is that one of them would give a meal to the other and fulfill mishloach manos, and then would join the recipient for the meal. Thus, the recipient gives back (as part of the meal) what he just received, and thereby also fulfills his obligation of mishloach manos.

> ורש"י ז"ל פירש זה אוכל עם זה בפורים של שנה זו ובשניה סועד חבירו עמו
>   וקשה על דבריו דא"כ לא היה מקיים מצות משלוח מנות אלא אחד מהם שהיה נותן
>   סעודתו לחבירו אבל חבירו לא היה מקיים וכן הקשה מהרי"ק ז"ל ול"נ לתרץ
>   דהיו עושין כך זה היה נותן סעודתו לחבירו במתנה בשנה זו ואחר שהיה שלו אז
>   חבירו כשהיה נותן לו מאותה סעודה והיה סועד עמו נמצא שגם הוא נותן לו
>   כיון שכבר היתה קנויה לו במתנה והרי נתן מהנתון לו

Thus, the Lechem Mishneh explicitly states that (at least according to Rashi) one can give mishloach manos to someone from the very mishloach manos that that person just gave him.

However, the [Peri Chadash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hezekiah_da_Silva) ([O.C. 695:4](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x3115)) gives a similar interpretation of Rashi, except that he says that only the first giver fulfills his obligation but the second guy does not.

> וכתב רש"י ז"ל מחלפי סעודתייהו זה אוכל עם זה בפורים של שנה זו ובשניה
>   סועד חבירו עמו ע"כ והקשה בב"י ז"ל דאם כן לא היו מקיימים ומשלוח מנות
>   איש לרעהו ולי נראה שכונת רש"י ז"ל לאשמועינן שאותו ששולח הסעודה היה
>   מיפטר ממשלוח מנות אף על פי שהיה הולך ואוכל שם עם חבירו אבל חבירו ודאי
>   דלא מיפטר בהכי

This might indicate that "recycled mishloach manos" is not valid, but perhaps he means that inviting someone for your meal does not count as mishloach manos – you have to actually send the guy a gift of food. In fact, several other acharonim do mention such a distinction in explaining Rashi:

[Darchei Moshe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moses_Isserles) ([O.C. 695](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x2822))

> ואיני יודע מאי קשיא למר **דאף אי סבירא ליה משלוח מנות איש לרעהו הוא
>   דוקא ובעי שילוח ממש ולכן אם אוכל עם חבירו אינו יוצא מכל מקום אין זו
>   קושיא דאפשר דרש"י סבירא ליה דמשלוח לאו דוקא אלא הוא הדין אם אוכל עם
>   חבירו דמאי שנא אם אוכל עמו בביתו או ששלח אליו** ואי קשיא ליה דאם אחד
>   היה אוכל עם חבירו בשנה זו אם כן השני לא היה מקיים משלוח מנות באותו
>   פורים וכן השני בפורים הבא אם כן מאי קאמר בסוף דבריו אם כן מאי אתא
>   לאשמועינן דסגי אשמועינן דהאחד יוצא במה שחבירו אכל עמו ולכן אין לדחות
>   דברי רש"י מכח קושייתו

[Eliah Rabba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elijah_Spira) (O.C. 695:10)

> פירש הר"ן הא דבמגילה דף אביי ורב חנניא מחלפי סעודתייהו להדדי והנה
>   בתאוה לעינים הקשה מאי קמ"ל הא כל שלוח מנות הוי הכי ולענ"ד הו"א כיון
>   שאין לו כדי וכו' אינו חייב כלל קמ"ל דאפילו הכי חייב והנה רש"י פירש
>   מחלפי סעודתייהו זה אוכל עם זה בפורים של שנה זו ובשנייה סועד חבירו עמו
>   ונ"ל דקשה לרש"י על פירוש הר"ן דעיקר חסר בש"ס והו"ל לפרש שלא היה להם
>   כדי לשלוח וכו' והנה הב"י הקשה על רש"י דא"כ לא היו מקיימין משלוח מנות
>   וא"ת שהיו שולחין מנות א"כ מאי קמ"ל ע"כ ונ"ל דלא קשה מידי דקמ"ל דמצוה
>   שיאכל אחד עם חבירו ולא ישב לבדו וכמ"ש בס"ק (ז') [ד'] וכל האחרונים דחקו
>   בפרש"י ולענ"ד כן נכון כפשטיה וכדפירשתי **ומשמע לי דבב"י הנ"ל דבאכילת
>   חבירו אצלו לא קיים משלוח מנות אפילו בעל הסעודה דשלוח ממש בעינן** אבל
>   בלחם משנה פ"ב דמגילה הבין קושית ב"י על האורח שלא קיים אבל בעל הסעודה
>   קיים בזה שחבירו אוכל אצלו על כן תירץ ופירש דבריו דהיו עושין כך זה היה
>   נותן סעודתו לחבירו במתנה בשנה זו ואחר שהיה שלו אז חבירו קיים כשבעל
>   הסעודה אוכל עמו כיון שכבר היתה קנויה לו במתנה ע"כ ולענ"ד אינו כן אלא
>   כוונת ב"י כדפירשתי ובלאו הכי תירוצו דחוק ועיקר חסר אבל הב"ח כתב כיון
>   דטעם משלוח מנות הוא כדי שישמח ממש עם אוהביו א"כ הוא הדין בסועד אצל
>   רעהו פטורים שניהם משלוח מנות ובתאוה לעינים פירש דמיירי שהתנה שיאכל עמו
>   בשנה האחרת וא"כ הו"ל בפורים ראשון כאילו גם הוא אוכל עמו ויוצאים שניהם
>   גם מג"א וט"ז נדחקו בפרש"י ומשמע שהבינו בב"י כלחם משנה וכבר כתבתי מה
>   שנ"ל לפי האמת ואין להאריך

[Peri Megadim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_ben_Meir_Teomim) ([Mishbetzos Zahav 695:5](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x3200))

> מחליף. עיין ט"ז והבין בב"י דודאי זה שמזמין חבירו לסעוד אצלו יוצא ידי
>   חובתו אלא הקושיא הוא איך יוצא חבירו בהאי שתא כו' ועיין דרכי משה צידד
>   בכוונת קושית הב"י **או דגם המזמין אינו יוצא ידי חובתו דבעינן שילוח
>   דוקא רש"י סובר דלאו דוקא שילוח** ואי דקשיא ליה על חבירו וא"כ מאי קושיא
>   מה קא משמע לן הא טובא קא משמע לן דמזמין יוצא והיינו דלב"י נמי מאי אתא
>   לאשמעינן ולפי מה שכתב הט"ז י"ל דלב"י אשמעינן דלא תימא דהוה הלוואה
>   גמורה קא משמע לן דיוצאין אבל לרש"י מאי קא משמע לן **דפשיטא ליה דשילוח
>   הוא לאו דוקא** הוא הדין מזמין יוצא ועיין פרי חדש משמע שמפרש מחלפי
>   לרש"י שאחד שולח סעודתו לחבירו ויוצא ידי חובתו אע"פ שהולך אח"כ לסעוד
>   אצלו **משמע שילוח ממש בעינן** ובלחם משנה כתב זה שלח סעודתו לחבירו והוה
>   של חבירו ואח"כ הלך זה אצלו לסעוד ויוצאין שניהם ומרש"י משמע שמזמין
>   חבירו אצלו ומכל מקום משמע דשילוח לאו דוקא הוה

However, a different potential issue with "recycled mishloach manos" is raised by the Taz. In his explanation of Rashi he mentions that one might have thought that because the two fellows were planning on reversing the meal invitation the next year it would not count as mishloach manos because it looks like lending/borrowing rather than giving. He goes on to note that if they made this arrangement within the same year then it would actually be real lending/borrowing:

[Turei Zahav](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_HaLevi_Segal) ([O.C. 695:5](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x3076))

> בגמ' אמרי' אביי בר אבין ור"ח בר אבין מחלפי סעודתייהו להדדי ופי' הר"ן
>   לא היה א' מהם כדי לשלוח ולהשאיר לעצמו ולפיכך כל אחד שולחים סעודתן זה
>   לזה כדי לאכול סעודת פורים ולקיי' מצות משלוח מנו' ודרך זה כתוב כאן
>   ורש"י פי' מחליפין סעודתייהו זה אוכל עם זה בפורים של שנה זו ובשני סועד
>   חבירו עמו והקשה ב"י לפירש"י דא"כ לא היה מקיימים משלוח מנות איש לרעהו
>   וא"ת שהיו שולחין מנות איש לרעהו א"כ מאי קמ"ל עכ"ל ונלע"ד לרש"י הוה
>   רבותא בזה שהיו אומרים בפי' שזה יאכל עם זה ואח"כ להיפוך וה"א דהוה כמו
>   הלואה ואין כאן מנות דהוא מתנ' דוקא קמ"ל דאפ"ה היו יוצאים דהיינו שבשנה
>   זו יצא זה שמזמין לחבירו וחבירו היה שולח לאיש אחר ולשנה שניה היה להיפוך
>   אלא שיש לדקדק למה לא פירש"י באמת הכל על שנה א' ושניהם יצאו ואפשר לו'
>   דבזה הוה באמת הלואה גמורה כיון שנראה לכל שתיכף מקבל תשלומין והיה תנאי
>   ביניהם משא"כ אם היו בשני שנים לא היה נראה כמו תשלומין בשנ' זו ולא בזו
>   ודוגמ' לזה מצינו בסי' ק"ע סי"ג בהג"ה לא יאמר אדם לחבירו בא ואכול עמי
>   מה שהאכלתני דהו' כפורע לו חובו ונרא' כאלו הלו' לו ויש לחוש שיאכילהו
>   יותר ואית ביה משום ריבית אבל מותר לומר לו בוא ואכול עמי ואאכול עמך פעם
>   אחרת ומותר לאכול עמו אפי' סעודה יותר גדולה עכ"ל הרי דבשעת אכילה השניה
>   אסור להזכיר שהוא תשלומין ה"נ כן דאז הוה הלואה כנלע"ד נכון

**In Sum:**

The Lechem Mishneh appears to explicitly allow "recycled mishloach manos", and while the Peri Chadash disagrees in that specific case it is likely for a different reason. Another potential issue is raised by the Taz, but it is not mentioned by the other acharonim and it is only according to Rashi whom everyone (Rambam, Shulchan Aruch, et al) ruled against.

Answer (score 3):

This is not explicit, but seems to me a pretty clear indication that it is ok:

The Mishnah Berura, quoting P'ri Megadim, equates trading with giving and then taking back, and in fact derives the latter from the former (694:2):

> אם החליף סעודתו בשל חבירו יצא ידי מתנות וע"כ עני המתפרנס מן הצדקה יתן שתי מתנות לשני אביונים ויחזרו הם ויתנו לו
>
> If one trades his meal with another, he has fulfilled the obligation of giving. *Therefore*, a pauper who is supported from charity should give two presents to two poor people, and then they should give it right back to him.

Regarding *mishloach manos* it is explicit in the Gemara (Megillah 7b) that trading meals fulfills the *mitzvah*. Accordingly, receiving and then giving back should be acceptable as well.

Comment: Very good find. What strengthens this answer and is implied here, but not explicitly stated, is that the purpose of *Matanot L'evyonim* is to provide food for someone else's *se'udah*. IIRC, O.C. somewhere recommends giving specifically **cooked** food that can be used for the meal. Today, most people overload the boxes with candies, chips and wafers.

Comment: @DanF The Ran writes as much about matanos l'evyonim. In my family we do not give "junk food" for the two reasons that (a) what you said (food for the meal is the primary mitzvah) and (b) what you said (everyone gets way too much of it).

Comment: I don't think the Mishna Berura derived the latter from the former – the Peri Megadim only states the latter. If anything, once we know that the latter is allowed the former will certainly be allowed. But this is referring to Matanos L'evyonim not Mishloach Manos.

Comment: @Alex I don't know what you mean with your first point - P'ri Megadi says the first, and then says לפיכך the second. As for as it being referring to Matanos L'evyonim, that was the point of my final paragraph.

Comment: Where does the Peri Megadim say that? In 294:1 he says ה״ה כאן עני המתפרנס מצדקה יתן ב׳ מתנות לב׳ אביונים ויחזרו הם ויתנו לו

Comment: @Alex P'ri Megadim refers you to Y.D. 251:12, which is the halacha that two עניים can give their tzedakka to each other, and says ה"ה to here. I assume that is why the Mishna Berura quotes him that way. But we need not argue about the P'ri Megadim - Mishna Berura says what I quoted no matter how you'd like to understand the P'ri Megadim.

Comment: Maybe it's just stam a קשיא on the Mishna Berura, but the first part is from the Gemara and the second part is from the Peri Megadim, and it does not seem that they are talking about the same thing. The Gemara indicates that Mishloach Manos can be traded, but the second half is referring to Matanos L'evyonim. That that can be given and given right back is based on the laws of General Tzedaka in Yoreh Deiah, not the Gemara in Megilla (at least per the Peri Megdim that the Mishna Berura is citing). Because this is a din in tzedaka, it would not necessarily apply to Mishloach Manos.

Answer (score 2):

[Over at the Otzar Hachochma Forum](http://forum.otzar.org/viewtopic.php?t=8494), one aspect of this is discussed:

Hi Sichasi notes that even in a regular case of returning Mishloach Manos (with different foods), the returner may not be Yotzei:

> דומני שראיתי בשם הצפנת פענח שבהשבת משלוח מנות לא יוצאים ידי"ח כיון שהוא בתורת גמול על שנתנו לו

While I don't believe this is the accepted opinion (see there at length), it is a reason why giving someone back their Mishloach Manos would not fulfill the Mitzvah.

Answer (score 1):

Why wouldn't it work? The [Peri Megadim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_ben_Meir_Teomim) ([Mishbetzos Zahav 694:1](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x3200)) rules that mishloach manos as a matana al menas lehachzir is invalid, but only because the recipient cannot use the food/drink for his meal which undermines the purpose of mishloach manos. But as long as there is no stipulation that it be returned, it would seem to be valid even if the recipient voluntarily chose to return it.

Comment: I thought of that, but that's only for the original giver, not for the second guy.  Sort of.  (Essentially what I'm saying is that there are other potential issues.)

Comment: @רבותמחשבות What would be the other issues?

Comment: the one I noted in my answer, since maybe it is being given just as a gift in return, not Mishloach Manos

Comment: @רבותמחשבות Why would we assume that it's not being given as mishloach manos (unless the person already fulfilled his obligation, but then the whole question is moot)?

Comment: Because the other person just gave him a gift, so he is giving it back because he feels like he has to.

Comment: Person B accepted mishloach manot from person A. It's now his to do what he wishes. Is there any specific halacha that says that the receiver must eat the food? I don't think so. So, now that B owns this, why can't he just return it to A and fulfill one of the 2 people? For that matter, once he returns it, can B give it back to A again? Is there anything that says that mishloach manot must be given to two **different** people?

Comment: @רבותמחשבות I would think that if he hasn't given mishloach manos yet he would just give it as mishloach manos. Especially because giving back the exact gift seems like a strange way to match a gift. If anything one could make the argument that giving a new mishloach manos to someone who just gave you shouldn't count.

Comment: @DanF You only need to give one person.