# Can people take Mishloach Manot?

Tags: mitzvah, purim, ownership

Is there an operative element to Mishloach Manot that requires a sending, i.e. a physical transfer from person to person? (related sources in [these](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/56175/can-a-shaliach-assemble-your-mishloach-manot-for-you) related [questions](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/56105/sending-mishloach-manot-by-serving-them) )

If I must travel on Purim, I would want to leave bowls of food on my property. I would invite people to come and take.

Assuming that I can be sure that people will come and take and that they will take 2 foods, am I mekayem the mitzvah because the food switches into their reshut (though without a shali'ach or any work by me)?

Then, if I can be, how does the possibility that people either won't show up or won't take the proper amount fit in? Does that invalidate the entire possibility, or because it is a doubt, we look for leniency?

Comment: The same doubt applies any time you send via messenger, no? Maybe your messenger will goof up.

Comment: possible dupe https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/69548/759

Comment: In that question, I have effected the change in reshut by placing it according to the answer. Here I have not done so. And here I am not explicitly designating a shaliach (can the recipient be considered a shaliach of the sender?)

Comment: While I have seen many people leave the package at someone's door if they are not home when they arrive, I wonder about the concept of "sending" (*mishloach*). I.e. can sending be like mail delivery, where you don't have to be home, but the letter / packaged has been considered sent.

Comment: @DoubleAA A shaliach may have a chazaka on his side.

Comment: @Yez does that chazaka derive from his formal status or from the fact that when you ask people to do things they do them?

Answer (score 1):

In [this answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/89806/13438) I quoted several acharonim who entertain the idea that an actual "sending" is necessary.

Darchei Moshe O.C. 695

Eliah Rabba O.C. 695:10

Peri Megadim Mishbetzos Zahav 695:5

Arguably  Peri Chadash O.C. 695:4

See there at length.

Comment: It’s always better to include relevant information in the post itself.